# Jira using GitHUB instead of Git

Tags: github, jira, jira-plugin

My understanding is that GitHUB adds functionality to Git that Jira also adds. So what's the point of connecting Jira to GitHUB instead of to Git directly?

It seems my question is difficult to understand. Let me ask differently. Why would it be better to install **Jira with GitHUB** as opposed to **Jira with Git**

Further clarification: It is not part of the question if a Jira/Git integration without GitHUB exists or not.

Comment: If you want to use Jira (you find it valuable).

Answer (score 1):

git is a version control system, while Github is a service that allows for hosting your projects online, adds a graphical user interface to git, and allows you to collaborate with other users

Comment: I can't find any documentation that it does, as far as I know Jira-git integration relies on a git based service such as Github, Bitbucket, etc if you want that functionality

Answer (score 0):

JIRA is used to track issues, bugs, improvements in form of tickets. It's used in agile methodologies.
git(local) and github(global) are used for version control.

Connecting JIRA to github allows you to automatically reference JIRA tickets in git commits.

For example JIRA issue is `"issue111"`. You mention it in git commit:
`"issue111 initial commit"`. Then if you check issue111 in JIRA you will see in Development section: `1 branch, 1 commit etc.` links which you can click to see the commit